# Ordenar objetos en JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Amigos, necesito una ayuda:
tengo un arreglo de objetos y necesito ordenarlo de menor a mayor por la edad usando el metodo sort.
cuando lo hago solamente con la variable funciona bien, pero cuando lo hago dentro de una función ya no funciona.

```js
function ordenar(usuarios) {
  usuarios.sort((a, b) => {
      if (a.edad < b.edad){
          return -1
      }if(a.edad > b.edad) {
          return 1
      }else {
          return 0;
      }
  })
}

const theArray = [
    { name: 'Luis', email: 'luis@gmail.com', edad: 70, },
    { name: 'Andrea', email: 'andrea@gmail.com', edad: 30 },
    { name: 'María', email: 'maria@academlo.com', edad: 50 }
]
console.log(ordenar(theArray))
```

salida: Undefined

Comment: Sale `undefined` porque tu función no devuelve nada. Escribe `return usuarios;` después de hacer el `sort` y comenta el resultado

Answer (score 1):

Esto sucede ya que tu función `ordenar()` no está retornando el resultado, tienes que agregar return usuarios; al final y tu código debería de funcionar:

```js
function ordenar(usuarios) {
  usuarios.sort((a, b) => {
      if (a.edad < b.edad){
          return -1
      }if(a.edad > b.edad) {
          return 1
      }else {
          return 0;
      }
  })
  return usuarios;
}

const theArray = [
    { name: 'Luis', email: 'luis@gmail.com', edad: 70, },
    { name: 'Andrea', email: 'andrea@gmail.com', edad: 30 },
    { name: 'María', email: 'maria@academlo.com', edad: 50 }
]
console.log(ordenar(theArray))
```